# Dynkin diagrams question

Tags: tikz-pgf

A MathOverflow user had some [trouble](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338544/dynkin-diagrams-and-graphs-in-latex) asking on MathOverflow about how to draw the Dynkin diagrams from pages 56 and 57 of Humphrey's book **Introduction to Lie Groups and Representation Theory**. He seems to be unclear how to ask here, so I thought I would ask (and answer) his question myself. How do you draw those diagrams?

Answer (score 5):

[image: Humphrey's diagrams]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\begin{document}
Page 56:
\pgfkeys{/Dynkin diagram,arrows=false}
\[
\begin{array}{cc}
A_1 \times A_1 & \dynkin{A}{1}\dynkin{A}{1}\\
A_2                     & \dynkin{A}{2}\\
B_2                     & \dynkin{B}{2}\\
G_2                     & \dynkin{G}{2} 
\end{array}
\]

Page 57:
\pgfkeys{/Dynkin diagram,arrows=true}
\[
\begin{array}{cc}
B_2                     & \dynkin{B}{2}\\
G_2                     & \dynkin{G}{2} 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```