# Graphs of Lie algebras in Latex

Tags: diagrams, graphs

For example, I have this

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{book} 
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\begin{document} 
\[ 
\begin{array}{cc} 
A_1 \times A_1 & \dynkin{A}{1}\dynkin{A}{1} \\ 
A_2 & \dynkin{A}{2} \\ 
B_2 & \dynkin{B}{2} \\ 
G_2 & \dynkin{G}{2} 
\end{array} 
\]
\end{document}
```

I would like to have a larger graph, and also I would like to give names to vertices like in chapter 13 page 145 of the book cited in a related [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504607/dynkin-diagrams-question).

Comment: The formatting is unreadable (please format code as a block of code) and the question is not specific enough for me to know what you would like. Can you provide an example of the output you want?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! He might know when you properly format the code. select the code block and use the '{}' on top of the edit window. To address someone please use @... this regarding your "Answer"

Answer (score 5):

First an unrelated comment: use `\[ ... \]`, not `$$ ... $$` for display math, see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/).

As mentioned in section 2 of the `dynkin-diagrams` manual, you can set global options for how the diagrams should look. For example with

```
\pgfkeys{
  Dynkin diagram,
  edge length=1cm,
  root radius=2pt
}
```

you get 1cm between the dots in your diagrams, and the dots get a radius of 2pt.

For labels, the package has options for this. I don't have the book you are referring to (so a description, or sketch, would be more helpful), but for example with `\dynkin[labels={a,b}]{A}{2}` the two vertices get the labels a and b below them.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{book} 
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\pgfkeys{
  Dynkin diagram,
  edge length=1cm,
  root radius=2pt
}
\begin{document} 
\[
 \begin{array}{cc}
  A_1 \times A_1 & \dynkin{A}{1}\dynkin{A}{1} \\
  A_2 & \dynkin[labels={a,b}]{A}{2} \\
  B_2 & \dynkin{B}{2} \\
  G_2 & \dynkin{G}{2}
\end{array} 
\] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Torbjorn T.